# How to use some string param for an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Example:

```
var v1 = "['a']";
var v2 = "['b']['c']";
var obj = {a: 'a', b: {c: "['b']['c']"}};
```

Is it possible to use 'v1' or 'v2' like a method for 'obj'? I need it for API because I do not know what should I parse. It can be obj['a'] or obj['b']['c']. Any solutions?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You need to know the full path of the key you're looking for. Consider flattening the structure or using an ES6 Map.

Comment: You could extend obj with a function that takes a string as a parameter (i.e. v1, v2) and then parses it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I was talking about, extending your object with a function that parses the string input and looks up the corresponding element.

A big caveat here is that I was lazy about handling of quotations, so you'll need to fiddle it a bit to handle single and double quotes. I haven't extensively tested, but I think it will return undefined when there's no match in the object.

```js
var v1 = "['a']";
var v2 = "['b']['c']";
var obj = {
  getByStr: function(str) {
    var args = str.replace("['", '').replace(new RegExp("'\]" + '$'), '').split("']['");
    var match = this[args.shift()];
    while(match !== undefined && args.length > 0)
      match = match[args.shift()];
    return match;
  },
  a: 'a',
  b: {
    c: "['b']['c']"
  }
};

document.write('v1 -- ' + obj.getByStr(v1) + '<br />');
document.write('v2 -- ' + obj.getByStr(v2) + '<br />');
```

If you think you might use it, but there's anything you don't understand in there, post a comment and I'll add some clarifications.